# Dockerfile entrypoint conflicts with docker-compose context

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker setup that does not have the Dockerfile or docker-compose at the root because there are many services.

```
build
 client.Dockerfile
deployments
 docker-compose.yml
web
  core
    scripts
      run.sh
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./build/client.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./web/core:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 35729:35729
```

And then the dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.11

ADD web/core/yarn.lock /yarn.lock
ADD web/core/package.json /package.json

ENV NODE_PATH=/node_modules
ENV PATH=$PATH:/node_modules/.bin
RUN yarn

WORKDIR /app
ADD web/core /app

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 35729

RUN cat /app/scripts/run.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/app/scripts/run.sh"]
CMD ["start"]
```

Now the RUN command displays the result of the file so it is there. However, when running `docker-compose up` the `client_1  | /bin/bash: /app/scripts/run.sh: No such file or directory`

I'm guessing it has something to do with the docker-compose context because when the dockerfile was at the root, it seemed to work fine.

I'm getting the feeling that docker is designed essentially to work only at the root.

Context:

I want a live reloading create-react-app server like this: https://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-to-create-react-app-with-docker.

I would like to setup my project this way: https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your volume is wrongly mounting. This should fix the issue. I created the similar folder structure. From the root folder of `build` ran `docker-compose -f ./deployments/docker-compose.yml up`. It works normally only thing i change volume path.

```
volumes:
  - ../web/core:/app
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that but same error `ERROR: for deployments_client_1  Cannot start service client: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"/app/scripts/run.sh\": stat /app/scripts/run.sh: no such file or directory"
`

Comment: I changed the answer please have a look this should fix the issue :)

Comment: That was it! That makes sense too.